# is possible to convert any code in native android to xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I was a Android developer and now  I am studying `Xamarin` , but I always ask myself  "can I convert all android(ios) code to `xamarin.android or xamarin.ios` ?" because I know c# is similar to java . However , they still have a few different syntax . Can someone help me answer this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin allows you to write Android apps in C#. It also allows you to use existing Java code in your solution. This is done by creating *bindings*, which is the bridge between managed code and the Android runtime.

For more information see:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/

Comment: So , i can convert 100% code java or just about 80% ?? :D

Comment: You're not really converting Java to C#. You can either write your code in C# and call all the native Android APIs as well as .NET framework. If you want to use Java code you will need to compile it and create a Jar file. Then create binding to use it from C#. In other words,  Xamarin does not compile or translate Java code to C#.